# Is there a non-equivalent pair of types containing, respectively, `int const` and `const int`?

Tags: c++, types

As we know, `int const` and `const int` are "type synonyms".

I told somebody earlier that they are equivalent "if that's the whole type" (i.e. if there are no more tokens in the `typename`).

But, now that I think about it, is there a pair of types which lexically contain, respectively, `int const` and `const int`, which are *not* equivalent?

Comment: `mint const` and `const intro` perhaps?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Hah, troll ;)

Comment: I was thinking of cheating a bit harder: `constexpr char firstChar(const char* str) { return *str; }` -- and then `char[firstChar("const int")]` versus `char[firstChar("int const")]` :) I'm not sure if this is a valid use of `constexpr`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I already sent a proposal to add `mint` as "an implementation-specific type large enough to refresh any breath representable on the current platform".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit While I do appreciate corrections on my English, I looked it up after your comment and found multiple people asking whether to use "if" or "whether" in the given context, and being told either is acceptable, as is the third option of simply omitting the word.

Comment: @hvd: Those people are wrong! And mostly North American. \*cries\* Actual _English_ people are not so forgiving. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit FWIW, I'm not American and I do care about using the language correctly. I'll look into it a bit more, and if I find anything supporting your correction, I'll avoid making the mistake again.

Comment: @hvd: A dictionary might be a good start. :) Love, me _[edit: a real one, rather than one of these un-reviewed US internet monstrosities]_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, but the first three UK results I was able to find also agree with me. http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv179.shtml http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page33.shtml http://www.english-grammar-lessons.co.uk/easily_confused/if_and_whether.htm I've made an honest effort to figure it out, but I don't see any support for your point of view.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You'd need a Victorian style guide, not a modern dictionary, to learn about antiquated proscriptions such as that one.

Comment: I freely admit it's difficult to find online resources that don't also pander to the recent trend of abandoning "whether". It's hardly _Victorian_, but short of showing you around the streets of a British city there's not much more I can do. :) [it's slightly disconcerting that at least one of you already lives in one, though!] Anyway...

Comment: The English grammar we used at school (that supposedly refers to British English) says that both *if* and *whether* are allowed for indirect speech - my 2¢.

Comment: @Matteo: They taught dropping the `s` after the `'` for singular possessives at mine. It makes me mad to this day! This may well be a case of a term falling out of favour (I heard a song on the radio this morning called "if it _was_ real" that made me cringe) and I just have to learn to deal with it \*cries\*

Comment: If it's any consolation, for both of those I *have* been taught the same as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so, unless you add some other qualifiers:

```
const int x;
volatile const int x;
```

But:

```
volatile const int x;
volatile int const x;
const volatile int x;
const int volatile x;
int const volatile x;
int volatile const x;
```

are all equivalent, though not all equally sensible.

Answer (score 2):

The order of declaration specifiers doesn't matter. This is legal C++11:

```
static long const unsigned inline long volatile int f() { return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` and `y` are technically two distinct types due to the fact that `int` has special meaning in bit-fields (`int` != `signed int` in them).

```
struct bitfield {
  const int x : 1;
};
int const y = 0;
```

Not entirely related, but still interesting.

Answer (score 0):

No. The context in which both forms could appear is a `type-id`. There is no context in which two type-id's could appear sequentially without a separator (usually `,` or `;`). Hence, the `const` is always part of the same `type-id` as the `int`.